# Recursion in memory

Tags: python, recursion

```
def rec(x):
    if x < 2:
        return 1
    else:
        a = rec(x-1)
        b = rec(x-2)
        return a+b
rec(4)
```

I don't understand this works in memory or why it returns 5. Could someone help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by “in memory”?

Comment: Maybe you're interested in learning more about [stack frames](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/recursion/explanation-of-recursion/).

Comment: Your `rec` computes the Fibonacci numbers.  You will find many, many discussions of recursive Fibonacci functions if you type “recursive” and “fibonacci” into your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Use print statements, it will make the recursion process more clear:
Basically it will keep calling `rec` over and over until it hits the "base case" which for you is when `x < 2`. It has to recursively call all the way down until it hits the base case, then come all the way back up.

Input

```
def rec(x):
    if x < 2:
        return 1
    else:
        print "x = ", x
        a = rec(x-1)
        print "a = ", a
        b = rec(x-2)
        print "b = ", b
        return a+b
rec(4)
```

Output

```
x =  4
x =  3
x =  2
a =  1
b =  1
a =  2
b =  1
a =  3
x =  2
a =  1
b =  1
b =  2
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets map out the calls:

```
                                  rec(4)
                rec(3)              +              rec(2)
      rec(2)       +     rec(1)     +      rec(1)    +      rec(0)
rec(1)  +  rec(0)  +       1        +        1       +        1
  1     +    1     +       1        +        1       +        1
```

So you can see there (and by looking at the code) that for each call of `rec(i)` where `i >= 2`, it splits into `rec(i-1) + rec(i-2)`, when `i < 2` we are at the base case and the call just returns `1`.  So by writing something like what I have done above you can trace through the calls until all you are left with is the base cases.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Cyber's answer, here's output that indicates the depth of recursion:

```
def rec(x, depth=0):
    print " "*(depth*3), "x =", x
    if x < 2:
        print " "*(depth*3), "=> 1"
        return 1
    else:
        a = rec(x-1, depth+1)
        print " "*(depth*3), "a =", a
        b = rec(x-2, depth+1)
        print " "*(depth*3), "b =", b
        print " "*(depth*3), "=>", a+b
        return a+b

rec(4)
```

Output:

```
 x = 4
    x = 3
       x = 2
          x = 1
          => 1
       a = 1
          x = 0
          => 1
       b = 1
       => 2
    a = 2
       x = 1
       => 1
    b = 1
    => 3
 a = 3
    x = 2
       x = 1
       => 1
    a = 1
       x = 0
       => 1
    b = 1
    => 2
 b = 2
 => 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume each indentation denotes another layer of recursion (it's in a deeper function call). Note that when x < 2, I assume you understand why rec(x) = 1.

```
rec(4)
    a = rec(3)
        a = rec(2)
            a = rec(1) = 1
            b = rec(0) = 1
            return a + b
        #a = 1 + 1 = 2
        b = rec(1)
        return a + b
    #a = 2 + 1 = 3
    b = rec(2)
        a = rec(1) = 1
        b = rec(0) = 1
        return a + b
    #b = 1 + 1 = 2
    return a + b
#rec(4) = 5
```